# Python: Localize start and end of the peak in signal

Tags: python, signal-processing

I'm struggling with a problem in python. I want to analyse a signal to obtain values shown in:

http://mri-q.com/uploads/3/4/5/7/34572113/3872153_orig.png.

I found multiple ways to find a location of a peak (like scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt or peakutils.peak.indexes), but have no idea of how one can calculate the start end end of the peak to find wash-in and wash-out time (or in other words the time when the blue area under curve starts and ends, respectively). Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: any update solutions to the answer? I am looking into similar problems too.